# Conceal Carry in NYC?

Tags: weapons, new-york-city

Due to the spate of antisemitic attacks in our neighborhood, I've been considering getting a conceal carry to go to and from work. I hear it's not easy to obtain a conceal carry in NYC.

Any clue as to if and how to obtain?

Comment: You don't appear to have done any research at all before asking this question. Permits are issued by NYPD, and the application process is online via their website, as any search engine can show you.

Answer (score 2):

New York is a "May Issue" state and thus, if you fill out all the proper paperwork and are cleared by all the proper legal hurdles, the permit may still not be issued for any reason the state feels is necessary (as opposed to "shall issues" which mandate permit approval with no additional hurdles).   NYC is one of the most restrictive areas in the U.S. for gun ownership so while you can apply for conceal carry quite easily, approval is usually based on "who you know" who can pull some strings for you.